# Encryption and Decryption In MVC 4

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a form where people enter the information such as credit card number and other sensitive information in asp.net MVC 4. I have a model class that will have the entity object and view will render the appropriate textbox or editor to enter those information. Then when the person clicks the submit button, the action method will be called and the information is captured and send to the server to store. I want to encrypt the data when the data is coming from the client so that it is protected? How to do that?

I understand that if I use [RequiresHttps] attribute in the controller class it will establish the secure connection using the certificate installed in the server? Can you please explain how this works?

Also, what is the best way of sending data from client to server in a secure fashion? Is there any other simpler techniques? Can you please explain how encrypt and decrypt will solve this problem?

Thanks in advance. BTW I am newbie to this technology.

Thanks

Comment: Here's the problem, you need to use an SSL certificate to encrypt all your communications, use database encryption with a secure key to encrypt CC info AND customer data, and lock down the unnecessary ports and access points on the server, etc., but that's not all.  If you are storing CC info on your server in a manner that is not fully PCI compliant, you could get sued if something leaks out, which is a real possibility if you are new to server and software security and PCI requirements. Why not just use a third party service like Stripe?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is install a SSL certificate from a trusted authority such as VeriSign, GeoTrust, Thawte etc... That will secure the communication between the client and the server.  You can read more about HTTPS on Wikipedia  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure

This however will not give you security.  You will need to ensure from a network level that your web server is secure, this will include ensuring there is a firewall on and proper security procedures on the server itself.  As a web developer your most trusted person to go to will be your company network security admin (I think all developers should learn to do this themselves so they know what's going on).

You will still need to secure your application.  My recommendation is to NEVER store credit card numbers in your system.  You are only asking for trouble if you do so.  For example if you store them in your database, even if encrypted, and your application is vulnerable to a SQL Injection you could expose all your customers credit card numbers to an attacker.  Even if encrypted, don't assume that you are safe because there are a lot of things dealing with encryption that you have to keep in mind including but not limited to:

1. The actual encryption is the easiest part of encryption there are a
   lot of good algorithms to choose from.
2. The hardest part is the key management
3. There are certain [weak keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key) for a lot of encryption algorithms
4. You may not choose a key that will give you good entropy (P@$$word is easy to guess)
5. How do you store your key securely?  If your application is vulnerable to a [path traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) attack a hacker may be able to get it off of your server very easily
6. Even if you do everything right, what happens if the network admin or another dev decides to be evil and steal your key and db? (Sorry network admins and other devs)

If you use a payment gateway like Authorize.NET, Paypal, etc... you can process the credit card without the need to store it.  As your controller receives it, you simply make a call to a service (usually just an XML call over HTTPS) and after getting a result just forget the credit card ever came to you.  You can store the transaction number they return back in case you need to void or refund the transaction later, or if you want to do an [authorization hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_hold) and then a capture later.

They even provide mechanisms for storing credit cards on their end with a token, and doing automated recurring billing.  Example would be Authorize.NET's advanced integration method https://developer.authorize.net/api/aim/   http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

this sample of encrypt and decrypt

```
 public static class lockIt
    {
        public static string EncryptString(string ClearText)
        {
            byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClearText);
            System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            string key1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            string key2 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key1);
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key2);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }

        public static string DecryptString(string EncryptText)
        {
            byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptText);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

            string key1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            string key2 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

            byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key1);
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key2);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateDecryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }

        public static string EnString(string instring)
        {
            return EncryptString(EncryptString(instring));
        }

        public static string DeString(string outstring)
        {
            return DecryptString(DecryptString(outstring));
        }
```